# How to get data from hook in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I use `hook` mechanism in Codeigniter. The kind of hook is `post_controller_constructor`.

There is one private object inside class hook`s:

```
private $settings = array();
```

This object is filled after executing hook.
How I can get access to `$settings` from libraries CI and controllers?

**Class:**

```
<? class LCode_module
{
    private $CI;
    private $_default_lang = "en";
    private $_sufixLangDefault = "_EN";
    private $allowedLanguages = array();

    private $_countryCurrent;
    private $countries = array();
    private $languages = array();
    private $settings = array();

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        /* Load lists */
        $this->CI->load->library('listdata');
        $this->countries['country'] = $this->CI->listdata->country;
        $this->countries['country_code'] = $this->CI->listdata->country_code;
        $this->countries['country_lang'] = $this->CI->listdata->country_lang;
        $this->languages = $this->CI->listdata->languages_sys;
    }

    public function route()
    {
      //Here I put data to $settings
    }

}
```

Method `route` is init method in `hook`

At the end of constructor:

```
/* Add object of class to GI instance */
$this->CI->LCode_module = new stdClass;
$this->CI->LCode_module->settings = &$this->settings;
```

After I try to get data in controller:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$c = $CI->LCode_module;
var_dump($c); // NULL
```

Comment: if it's a codeigniter core class, you shouldn't need to edit it and there should be some form of a `getter` to retrieve data from it. can you show more about the class?

Comment: Do you mean class of my hook?

Comment: the class wherever `private $settings = array();` is declared

Comment: Expanded question with code of class

Comment: oh it's your own class, just create the variable in the CI chain by adding `$this->CI->LCode_module_settings = &$this->settings` at the end of your constructor. then you can use `$this->LCode_module_settings` in your controllers to access the variable

Comment: So, will it give me filled object `$this->settings` after executing method `$route`? I seem `$this->CI->LCode_module_settings` will contain null object

Comment: which is why you store the reference to the property with the `&` symbol

Comment: Where is add this line? In the end of `route` method?

Comment: the end of your `__construct()` method

Comment: Why path is: `$this->CI->LCode_module_settings`,but not `$this->CI->LCode_module->settings`?

Comment: because `LCode_module` is not currently a property of the CI chain, so you'll receive an error of trying to access a property on an undefined variable, if you want it to work like that, then you'll need a line prior to it that goes like this: `$this->CI->LCode_module = new stdClass;`

Comment: Something wrong. I get empty object in controller: `$CI =& get_instance();
        $c = $CI->LCode_module_settings;`

Comment: Seems your way does not work. I updated question how I have tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95372/discussion-between-ahmed-and-iam-decoder).

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your class, I created a static option which you can use whenever you need:

```
<?php
class LCode_module
{
    private $CI;
    private $_default_lang = "en";
    private $_sufixLangDefault = "_EN";
    private $allowedLanguages = array();

    private $_countryCurrent;
    private $countries = array();
    private $languages = array();
    private $settings = array();

    private static $instance;
    private static $static_settings;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        /* Load lists */
        $this->CI->load->library('listdata');
        $this->countries['country'] = $this->CI->listdata->country;
        $this->countries['country_code'] = $this->CI->listdata->country_code;
        $this->countries['country_lang'] = $this->CI->listdata->country_lang;
        $this->languages = $this->CI->listdata->languages_sys;
        self::$instance = &$this;
        self::$static_settings = &$this->settings;
    }

    public function route()
    {
        //Here I put data to $settings
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if (is_null(self::$instance)) { self::$instance = new self(); }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function settings($key = NULL){
        $instance = self::getInstance();
        if(is_null($key)) return $instance::$static_settings;
        return (array_key_exists($key, $instance::$static_settings) ? $instance::$static_settings[$key] : null);
    }
}
```

Then you just call

```
LCode_module::settings()
```

when you need to retrieve the settings

This does imply parallel singleton use, which isn't exactly best practice, but it should do the trick for now since hooks only get loaded once. I'm sure CI has a way of performing this, but I'm drawing a blank on it right now.

Comment: May be call like as: `$CI->LCode_module::settings()`?. Because I get error: `Fatal error: Class 'LCode_module' not found`

Comment: nope you just call `LCode_module::settings()` static methods only require the class name and the method or property you want to access, the upside is removing the necessity for an instance of the object

Comment: then your hook is not being called

Comment: I tried how you tell, I get error: `Fatal error: Class 'LCode_module' not found in`

Comment: your hook is not being loaded at all

Comment: make sure you did everything according to the [CodeIgniter Hooks](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) docs

Comment: I did following this tutorial, but I have result object  which I need to share in my controllers. For this I need to get access